# R recursive join not getting desired results

Tags: r, join

I am working on recreating my Excel model in R due to the limited amount of data that Excel can process.  The meat of the model takes two columns of flight data (inbound leg, outbound leg) and builds out lines of flight by matching the outbound leg to the inbound leg, placing the new outbound leg on the original line and repeating this process until there is no more inbound match for the outbound leg.  Here is the working VBA code for this process.

```
    For i = f To l
        If i Mod 100 = 0 Then Application.StatusBar = "Progress: Step 4 of 18 - Building lines for " & ref.Cells(a, 39) & " (" & (a - 3) & " A/C types of " & (g - 3) & "), Line " & i - f & " of " & l - f & ")"
        DoEvents

    y = 0
    b = 0

        x = .Cells(i, 2)

        y = Application.Match(.Cells(i, 2), LegTable, 0)
        j = FirstTurn(y, 1)
        If .Cells(i, 2) <> FirstTurn(y, 1) Then GoTo Nexti

        NextLeg = NextLeg + 1
        ReDim Preserve NextTurn(0, 1 To NextLeg)
        NextTurn(0, NextLeg) = FirstTurn(y, 2)

            Do
                FTtext = FirstTurn(y, 2)
                On Error GoTo errhdlr
                b = Application.Match(FTtext, LegTable, 1)
                If FTtext <> FirstTurn(b, 1) Then GoTo Nexti

                NextLeg = NextLeg + 1
                ReDim Preserve NextTurn(0, 1 To NextLeg)
                NextTurn(0, NextLeg) = FirstTurn(b, 2)
                y = b
            Loop

errhdlr:
    Resume Nexti
Nexti:

    If NextLeg > 0 Then Range(.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(i, NextLeg + 2)).Value = NextTurn
    Erase NextTurn
    NextLeg = 0

    Next i
```

Sample data would be

```
In  Out
1   4
2   3
4   5
5   2
```

Output would be

```
1 4 5 2 3
2 3
4 5 2 3
5 2 3
```

In R, I have the following code

```
## Build Lines of Flight
  b.list <- list(a = data.frame(leg1, leg2), b = data.frame((leg2)))
  c.data <- join_all(b.list, by = leg2, type = "full", match = "all")
```

All this gives me is the original two columns.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: `join_all`, or any SQL style join, will never produce your desired output. The output you specify would not really fit properly in a data frame at all, given the ragged nature of the rows. Instead, your output will need to be a list, where each row is an element of the list. Other than porting your code directly into R, you might look at graph representation packages like **igraph**, where you might be able to extract this information as paths from a directed graph.

Comment: I thought that would be the case, but I was told a recursive join would work so I gave it a shot.

Comment: why does row `3` end with a `2`... isn't `2` always followed by a `3`?

Comment: not when it comes to flight numbers.  There is no pattern or sequencing with flight numbers which is what makes this difficult.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a mistake there? Why does 2 get followed by 3 in the other rows?

Comment: ok.  sorry I see what you are saying.  Yes, the third row should read 4 5 2 3.  Human error has been corrected.

Comment: Will there ever be a case in your data where an `in` value will be repeated with (same or different) `out` values?

Comment: no.  all values in IN are unique within the IN column and all values in OUT are unique within the OUT column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Mark, Roland, and Snoram, for the suggestions.  While trying to get those to work, I created a solution that works with my data.  Not sure how efficient it truly is, but it ran through 128K rows (ended up being 248 total columns wide) in less than 6 seconds so I can't complain (my excel model would take over 5 minutes for the same dataset).  Thanks again for the assistance.  Here is my code:

```
## Build Lines of Flight
nr <- nrow(b.data)
c <- 2
c.df <- b.df
nlegname <- paste("leg", c, sep = "")
y <- match(leg2, leg1)

while(all(is.na(y)) == FALSE)
  {
y <- match(c.df[[c]], leg1)
d <- all(is.na(y))
nl <- b.df[y,"leg2"]
c.df <- add_column(c.df, nleg = nl)
c <-c+1
nlegname <- paste("leg", c, sep = "")
names(c.df)[names(c.df) == "nleg"] <- nlegname
}
c.df[[c]] <- NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

I liked the challenge of your question, so here is a *not-so-elegant* solution using `base R`. You mentioned you are working with big datasets and this is going to rank amongst the slower solutions but I will share it anyway at least until other solutions arrive:

```
lines_list <- split(df, df$In)
for (i in 1:length(lines_list)) {
  while (TRUE) {
    n <- length(lines_list[[i]])
    row <- which(lines_list[[i]][[n]] == df$In)
    if (any(row)) {
      lines_list[[i]][paste0("Out", n)] <- df$Out[row]
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
}
lines_list
$`1`
  In Out Out2 Out3 Out4
1  1   4    5    2    3

$`2`
  In Out
2  2   3

$`4`
  In Out Out2 Out3
3  4   5    2    3

$`5`
  In Out Out2
4  5   2    3
```

Or you could take it back to a `data.frame` with something like:

```
data.table::rbindlist(lines_list, fill = TRUE)  
   In Out Out2 Out3 Out4
1:  1   4    5    2    3
2:  2   3   NA   NA   NA
3:  4   5    2    3   NA
4:  5   2    3   NA   NA
```

Comment: Awesome.  I will give this a shot.  I definitely like the data.frame output.

Comment: I think it is working, but I can't view the results.  I get the following error "cannot allocate vector of size 16.0 GB"  I am assuming it saying that the data.table is too large.  My real data has 25K rows (which is a small sample size of the data that will need to be processed)

Comment: I havent worked with this kind of data before but, like Mark I would be worried about infinite recursion...

Answer (score 1):

without talking about efficiency, yes, you could do a recursive join starting like:

```
DF <- data.frame(In = c(1,2,4,5), Out = c(4,3,5,2))

dplyr::left_join(DF, DF, by = c("Out" = "In"))

#   In Out Out.y
# 1  1   4     5
# 2  2   3    NA
# 3  4   5     2
# 4  5   2     3
```

and so on...
and later possibly re-shape into a list if you don't like the `NAs`

Comment: I am getting an error: `by` can't contain join column `leg21`, `leg22`, `leg23`, `leg24`, `leg25`, ... which is missing from LHS

Answer (score 1):

So, if you're working with really large data, the goal should be to minimize work.  In the example you gave, there's really only one full path, everything else is just a portion of that path (starting from 1).  I assume that your data doesn't contain any loops (4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4) because that would break this.

First, lets find all the unique starting points - these are the `in` values that are never in the `out`.  There should be at least one of these if the non-looping condition I assume is true.  We can also pull out all the other `in` locations that do have an `out`

```
b = data.frame(In = c(1,2,4,5), Out = c(4,3,5,2))

onlyStarting = b$In[!(b$In %in% b$Out)]
allOthers = b$In[b$In %in% b$Out]
```

Now we want a function that can get the paths for the starting points.  I wrote a recursive function that does this.  It finds the next step and calls itself until there are no more steps.

```
getNextStep = function(IN){
  nextStep = b$Out[b$In == IN]
  if(length(nextStep) == 0) return(IN)
  return(c(IN,getNextStep(nextStep)))
}
possiblePaths = lapply(onlyStarting,getNextStep)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 1 4 5 2 3
```

We got the full path. Now we just need to find all the sub paths.  We do this by checking each full path for the presence of the `in` and then returning the portion of the subpath we need.  This avoid lots of expensive recomputing that we don't need to bother with.

```
findMatch = function(IN,possiblePaths){
  fullPath = possiblePaths[[which(sapply(possiblePaths,`%in%`,x=IN))[1]]]
  partialPath = fullPath[which(fullPath == IN):length(fullPath)]
  return(partialPath)
}
otherPaths = lapply(allOthers,findMatch,possiblePaths)
otherPaths
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 2 3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 4 5 2 3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 5 2 3
```

Comment: I went ahead and did a microbenchmark on @snoram's answer versus mine (because he brought up the efficiency of his) and on this toy example, my laptop has my code at a median time of 205 microseconds vs 985 microseconds.

Comment: I'm a little bored in a meeting right now so I expanded the dataset to be `b = data.frame(In = c(1,2,4,5,8,9,12,10,7,100:199,300:499), Out = c(4,3,5,2,9,12,10,7,4,101:200,301:500))` and when running this, my recursive solution took 13 milliseconds compared to 2938 milliseconds with the loop.

Comment: Although, when I tried to have `b = data.frame(In = 1:24999,Out = 2:25000)` I did run into some infinite recursion problems, so hopefully your data isn't like that...